# Open folder in Windows Explorer from Cmd

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer

Say if I am navigating some folder in cmd such as E:\dir1\dir2

```
E:\dir1\dir2>
```

How can I open the folder quickly in Windows Explorer? Copying the whole path and pasting seems awkward.

There is an equivalent in Mac; an `open .` will do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`start .` or `explorer .` will open the current directory in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Or `explorer .`

Answer (score 5):

```
explorer .
```

will start Windows Explorer in the current directory.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.

Comment: @iglvzx It wasn't a dupe when it was posted (it was posted before you edited your answer and added it). :)

Comment: **Amazed** contributed `explorer .` first, so that's what I was meaning.

Answer (score 0):

To augment the accepted answer, if you are like me and will probably never remember `start .`, here is a simple batch file called `explore` you can put in your Environment Path:

```
@echo off
echo Opening %cd%
start .
```

[image]